# What's the preferred way to share a file on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if this is the right place, but can anyone tell me what is the best/safest (in privacy)/preferred way to share files on Stack Overflow without having to use my personal file hosting service like [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) or [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive)?

The file could be shared as part of the question or the answers.

I'm not looking for the Pros-Cons of sharing a file on Stack Overflow. "If sharing a file is the only way, then what is the best option that we have got?" is the question.

This is not for the usual coding questions that folks are used to on Stack Overflow. It is for software that are is coding related i.e., Tableau!

Comment: Really, you shouldn't do it at all. Your code should be in the question itself and if it depends on external libraries you would note that in your question.

Comment: @BSMP - I'm referring to questions on Tableau software which is not specifically a Coding Q&A. Many times it is easier to just share the file with the necessary text description rather than try to explain each and every step of the process.

Comment: @CodyGray - The question you are referring to is more of a "whether or not", rather than a "if yes, then what?". As explained in my earlier comment, it is lot more helpful if I can just share the file on the Tableau question rather than to write stepwise solution to how I arrived at the answer. In such a case, what is the best option that I have keeping in my mind all the points raised on the other question?

Comment: The answer is the same. This is not allowed, so there is no preferred way of doing it. It is not "a lot more helpful", it is completely *unhelpful* because then the required information is not part of the question itself. I and many other users absolutely *will not* download arbitrary files in order to help you. I would just downvote the question, vote to close as incompletely specified, and move along. I'm guessing you wouldn't find that helpful.

Comment: *is more of a "whether or not", rather than a "if yes, then what?"* - Because the answer isn't yes, it's no. *which is not specifically a Coding Q&A* - Are you sure the question is even on topic here?

Comment: "If sharing a file is the only way" to answer a question, that means the question is either off-topic or too broad. And if it isn't the only way, an answer which essentially depends on an external file is inadequate, for the reasons BSMP and Cody Gray mentioned.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'm actually looking to solve someone's problem in a more meaningful way along with screenshots and text. And it makes more sense for me to share the solution file with that person rather than to write a bunch of jargon.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045108/transfer-column-to-row-in-tableau/

I agree that Stackoverflow is built to solve Coder's problems but since it expanded to encompass all fields under the sun, ideally, I suppose, it should also help people answer in all ways possible, is all I'm saying! Didn't realize there would be such a backlash on this topic.

Comment: Can you direct me to the Visualization community of StackOverflow, under which software like Tableau fall? I hope, at least, there are no file sharing restrictions in that place. Update- I wonder, where the previous comment went.

Comment: I don't know where your comment went, and I don't know what you mean by "Visualization" community. I don't think we have one. This is a programming Q&A site. If this Tableau thing is not programming-related, then it is off-topic. If it is programming, you should be able to post the relevant code or repro steps in the body of a question or answer. Posts can be long if they absolutely need to be. I should know, I've written several half-books on this site. But we simply don't do external resources. Also, you need to realize that Q&A are supposed to be useful for others, too, not just the OP.

Comment: I was going to suggest [stats.se] seems like they include data mining and visualization http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour but there isn't a tag for Tableau.  You could go over and ask for an opinion on their meta?  Definitely ask before asking any questions on the main site.

Comment: *"Stackoverflow is built to solve Coder's problems but since it expanded to encompass all fields under the sun…"* – well, no, it hasn't. SO is still a site for programming questions and programming questions only. The only thing I'm willing to entertain a discussion about is if there's something that's clearly a programming tool/language, but which cannot productively be discussed in a text-only (+ some screenshots perhaps) medium. Is Tableau such a thing? (I don't know, truly) If so, you should open a discussion on how to deal with a visual language here, or something to that extend.